# Survey answers filtered by Country?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, survey, survey-2018

Great results of the [2018 survey](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/13/2018-developer-survey-results-live/?cb=1)!
Is there any chance one can see the survey results filtered by country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by the look of it.  Once the data has been released for download:

> Want to dive into the results yourself? In a few weeks, we’ll make the anonymized results of the survey available for download under the Open Database License (ODbL). We look forward to seeing what you find!

You can get it and sort it yourself (they are csv files).  For example the fourth column in last year's data shows the country.  You could exclude all other results that do not match you country and sort it yourself (painful I know) but you get custom searches.

Comment: thanks, I was looking for a way to  download it.  Will just have to wait :)

Comment: @Aurovrata  I've found the release date and where to get it from:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/13/2018-developer-survey-results-live/

Comment: thanks @Simon, I guess it will get listed [here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/) on 30th may.

Comment: I would of thought Stack Overflow would be more up to date with the tech. CSV is old school, what about JSON or even XML. Parsing CSV is going to be painful :(

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien  In general yes but there are clear reasons to use csv see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224929/is-csv-a-good-alternative-to-xml-and-json) page.

Comment: Thank @Simon that's helpful. Also note `dealing with legacy systems`, so that prove it, Stack Overflow is old school

Comment: CSV is good as you can use it with your favorite BI tool for building custom reports - like http://stackoverflow.seektable.com/ (currently only 2017 survey results are present as 2018 CSV is not available yet)